# EX4200 / EX3300 IPv6 Routing Question

Tags: routing, switch, ipv6, juniper-ex

we have about 5 Servers and currently only a cheap L2 Switch.

We got an /42 IPv6 Network assigned from our provider and want to route this /42 Network into multiple /64 subnets. These can just be static without any DHCP but they should have access to the internet.
In this case we want to upgrade our switch to an L3 Switch to support basic routing options.

We are thinking about a Juniper EX4200-48T or a Juniper EX3300-48T but we don't want to buy anything that expensive without knowing the switch is the right one.
Also we have seen we need an AFL license to enable all the L3 routing features and only basic L3 features are available without the AFL license.
Since nobody has done this before here, we are probably a little bit confused what exactly we are needing now.

Here is a little pull out of the EX4200 documentation:

> **Layer 3 Features: IPv6**
>
> - Max number of Neighbor Discovery (ND) entries: 16,000 (shared with IPv4)
> - Max number of IPv6 unicast routes in hardware: 4,000
> - Max number of IPv6 multicast routes in hardware: 2,000
> - routing protocols: rIPng, OSPFv3, IPv6, ISIS, BGP4+, PIM, MLD, MLDv2
> - Static routing

Am I right when I assume we just need "static ipv6 routing" for what we want to do?
And does anybody know whether static ipv6 routing is useable without an AFL license.
If someone has a better suggestion what we should do or which switch we need to do this I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

//Edit

We don't want to exchange subnet information with neighboring routers.
We only want that every server or virtual Server which is connected to that switch gets his own /64 subnet.
My thought was here, we just have to create for every subnet a static ipv6 route which is available without AFL (i think)

> **Router -> Juniper Switch**
>
> - Port1 = Server1 with its own /64 subnet
> - Port2 = Server2 with its own /64 subnet and every vserver on it
> - Port3 = Server3 with its own /64 subnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't trying to exchange subnet information with neighboring routers about these /64's, then you'll be fine with the stock EX4200 loadout.  However, if you were going to, you'll need routing protocol support (i.e. RIPng, OSPFv3, ISIS, BGP) that only comes with an AFL.  Given your design intentions, you don't need the AFL.

Check out Juniper's ["Understanding Software Licenses for EX Series Switches"](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/concept/ex-series-software-licenses-overview.html) to get more information into what you actually get with the AFL.

Note:  All of this functionality exists with/without the AFL, you simply get a warning/syslog message when you don't.  They go on more of an honor system.

Comment: thanks ! I updated my post above with additional information. So I am right with that we just have to create for every ipv6 subnet we want to have static route ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used EX4200 with IPv6 static routing. Works fine with default license. You can put /64 per VLAN and allocate each VLAN for each server. That will just do the required trick. And yes you do not need to exchange subnet info since servers will have default pointed towards switch.

Say you have got:

xxxx:xxxx:xxYY::/42

You can slice a /48 and eventually /64 from it.

xxxx:xxxx:xxYY::/42 > (take /48 slice off) > xxxx:xxxx:xxa1::/48

xxxx:xxxx:xxa1::/48 > (take /64 slice off) > xxxx:xxxx:xxa1:a::/64

So for your servers you can use:

xxxx:xxxx:xxa1:a::/64
xxxx:xxxx:xxa1:b::/64
xxxx:xxxx:xxa1:c::/64

And now for this you can put say xxxx:xxxx:xxa1:a::1 / 64 on say VLAN 100. So xxxx:xxxx:xxa1:a::1 will become GW and you can point server's default ::/0 towards it.

I hope this will help.